# diffeomorphism type of the connected sum of two differentiable manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, complex-geometry

I'm reading *Complex Geometry-An Introduction* by *Daniel Huybrechts* recently. And I meet a confusing question. In section 2.5, he gives an accurate definition of the connected sum of two smooth manifolds as follows:

Let $M$ and $M^{\prime}$ be differentiable manifolds both of dimension $m$. By $D \subset$ $\mathbb{R}^m$ we shall denote the open ball of radius one. Choose open subsets $U \subset M$ and $U^{\prime} \subset M^{\prime}$ and diffeomorphisms $\eta: D \cong U$ and $\eta^{\prime}: D \cong U^{\prime}$. Furthermore we consider the diffeomorphim
$$
\xi: D \backslash\left(\frac{1}{2} \bar{D}\right) \stackrel{\sim}{\longrightarrow} D \backslash\left(\frac{1}{2} \bar{D}\right), \quad x \longmapsto\left(\frac{1}{2}\|x\|^{-2}\right) \cdot x
$$
of the annulus $D \backslash\left(\frac{1}{2} D\right)=\left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^m \mid 1 / 2<\|x\|<1\right\}$.

**Definition 2.5.7:**
The connected sum
$$
M \# M^{\prime}:=\left(M \backslash \eta\left(\frac{1}{2} \bar{D}\right)\right) \bigcup_{\xi}\left(M^{\prime} \backslash \eta^{\prime}\left(\frac{1}{2} \bar{D}\right)\right)
$$
is obtained by gluing $M \backslash \eta\left(\frac{1}{2} \bar{D}\right)$ and $M^{\prime} \backslash \eta^{\prime}\left(\frac{1}{2} \bar{D}\right)$ over the open subsets $U \backslash \eta\left(\frac{1}{2} \bar{D}\right)$ and $U^{\prime} \backslash \eta^{\prime}\left(\frac{1}{2} \bar{D}\right)$ via the map $\xi$ (or, more explicitly, via $\eta^{\prime} \circ \xi \circ \eta^{-1}$ ).

But then he says that the diffeomorphism type of the connected sum does not depend neither on the chosen open subsets $U$ and $U^{\prime}$ nor on $\eta$ and $\eta^{\prime}$. I'm confused about this statement because I know some twisted spheres are not differentiable spheres. Can anyone give me a detailed explanation?

Comment: Are $M$ and $M^\prime$ connected?

Comment: Maybe he meant to say the "homeomorphism type."

Comment: What exactly is confusing you in relation with twisted spheres?

Comment: @Thomas Yes, they are both connected.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan But after the definition, the author shows that blow-up along a point is diffeomorphic to the connected sum with $\mathbb{P}^n$.

Comment: @Didier, Because I think a twisted sphere can be regarded as the conneced sum of two standard spheres by the boundary map.

Comment: The twisted sphere construction allows weird diffeos of neighborhoods if the boundaries of the disks.  Connect sum does not.

Comment: @Jason DeVito Is there a proof about the diffeomorphism type of the connected sum does not depend neither on the chosen open subsets $U$ and $U^{\prime}$ nor on $\eta$ and $\eta^{\prime}$?

Comment: That's not true, The diffeomorphism type *can* depend on the relative orientation of $\mu$ and $\mu^{\prime}$ (in case that $M$ and $M^{\prime}$ are oriented), but nothing more. The key to the well-definedness is Palais' disc theorem. This can be found in many Differential Topology texts, e.g. I think Hirsch has a section on it.